# Word for the case when something was but is absent now

Tags: word-choice

For example, I have three apples. I eat them one by one and after that I want to say there are no apples anymore. Is phrase "apples are ended" correct or should I use another verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ended" refers to a process, whereas "finished" and "gone" can refer to objects as well. 
"Ended" is also rather literary.

Answer (score 8):

The most natural way of saying it in Britsh English would be *The apples are all gone*.

Comment: Ditto for American English

Comment: And what about : *There aren't any apples left* ?

Comment: It would depend on the circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

'Apples are ended' doesn't sound correct because of the verb choice. I'd say 'The apples are finished' or the more obvious 'I ate all the apples'.

Comment: I don't really like "the apples are finished", it makes me wonder "What were the apples doing?"

Comment: "The apples are finished" sounds just as wrong as "The apples are ended".

Comment: @Marthaª: not to me. "All gone" is more likely, but I find nothing wrong with "The apples are finished, but there are still some bananas".

Answer (score 2):

I would use "the apples are finished," or possibly "the apples are no more," but that seems a bit dramatic.

Comment: "The apples are finished" sounds just as wrong as "The apples are ended". "I finished the apples", on the other hand, is perfectly fine.